Assign a number to the univocal rows that conform to a certain filter in array
I have the following table with the following columns:
Column 1: Account Nr.
Column 2: Partner
In Column 3 I added my desired result: Univocal Partner for each Account Nr., numbered



Account Nr.
Partner
Desired Result




2
C
1


2
B
2


2
B
2


3
B
1


3
C
2


4
F
1


4
F
1


4
G
2


4
A
3



I need a formula to insert in Column 3 that assigns a number to the univocal 'Partner' that each 'Account Nr' has. Explained in words:
For Account Nr. 2 there are two partners (C, B) so assign 1 to C, 2 to B.
For Account Nr. 3 there are two partners (B and C) so assign 1 to B and 2 to C.
For Account Nr. 4 there are three partners (F, G and A) so assign 1 to F, 2 to G, 3 to A.
The table is structured as a hierarchy so I can't sort the column for any value.
I tried combining COUNTIF and FILTER but apparently this does not support arrays.

Try using the following formula:


=XMATCH(B2,UNIQUE(FILTER(B$2:B$10,A$2:A$10=A2)))


If not using Structured References aka Tables then could spill the formula for the entire data using the following:
=LET(
     a, A2:B10,
     MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(x,
     XMATCH(INDEX(a,x,2),
     UNIQUE(FILTER(DROP(a,,1),
     INDEX(a,x,1)=TAKE(a,,1)))))))



Very tricky answer.

@MayukhBhattacharya: question on the snippet in relation to the formula provided: the highlighted blue border for the entire range C2:C10 seems to suggest that you are there using a spilled array, but you won't get that by using the formula provided. This needs to be dragged down. Or am I missing something? To get a spill, in my version at least (MS 365, v.2409), I would need something like: MAP($A$2:$A$10,$B$2:$B$10,LAMBDA(account_nr,partner,XMATCH(partner,UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$10,$A$2:$A$10=account_nr))))).

Hi @ouroboros1 sorry, yes I have pasted the snippet returned using an Dynamic array formula. The formula posted shouldn't be showing the blue border, which only appears when the DAF is applied. Perhaps this is the formula which you need to apply: =LET(a, A2:B10,MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),LAMBDA(x,XMATCH(INDEX(a,x,2),UNIQUE(FILTER(DROP(a,,1),INDEX(a,x,1)=TAKE(a,,1)))))))

@ouroboros1 also not posted the same because OP is using Structured Tables as per the post given, so didn't posted the DAF formula. Updated in post as well. Thank you!

Understood; my Excel-world makes sense again. Your LET option works to spill for simple ranges. So does the MAP option I provided in my previous comment. Unless I’m missing some potential edge case, but the results on this data are the same.

The use of SEQUENCE() + ROWS() is essential here. See both of these are self-referencing : INDEX(a,x,2) and INDEX(a,x,1) these two components acts like for each element in the array. It will iterate until and unless it reaches the instance where there is nothing to find. Consider this --> when we use UNIQUE() within MAP() or BYROW() what it does, it iterates through each element of the unique array, likewise, our array is the concern here so to lookinto each we are using SEQUENCE() otherwise it wont work like you did, and will give false positives,.

Sequence is not essential if you use it like: =MAP(A2:A10,B2:B10,LAMBDA(a,b,ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:b,A2:a=a)))))

@P.b Sir. amazing.

@MayukhBhattacharya inspired by your solution.
